# PayPal "Buy it Now" link broken

Tags: paypal

My lead generation platform allows people to pay for the ability to connect with potential leads. PayPal's "Buy It Now" link just recently stopped working. Nothing changed on my end.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="H2BZKXHJRX23C">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Meet Saifur Rahman Mohsin">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="385">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.55">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.dazah.com/payments/ipn">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="63333231653936303331366462343736393366323465626365373234626430633039636330306131356534653963633037623338663064616263653264613365393131303435633630333762393863346163303165656333346336313339303234623337646662623661653033346530346334363066396566636637386333355746376675413858796936667a55387963667a436859722b584230442f45505179636d31376c556d53576c6357704b4d68426c6d7659684c51664955636e6171">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.dazah.com/">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.dazah.com/">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">$0.55 to Meet</button>
</form>
```

I get just a generic page that says: "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

I attempted to just use a Paypal Hosted button (replacing the input name="business") but it doesn't seem to allow me to pass in an amount when I do that? It just always asks the end user to enter the item amount. Not sure what I'm doing wrong there either.

Help appreciated, thanks!

~~~~~

UPDATE: I figured out that it's the 'custom' field that is breaking it. It never used to. Anyone know why that is? Is custom no longer supported?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation of 256 bytes on the length of value of variable 'custom'. Please shorten it and try again.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that limit. However, if it's too long, it just chops it off. Or at least that's what used to happen. Now for some reason it throws an error at any length.

Comment: There was an update for PayPal WPS in Mar 29th. The feature change would probably be caused by that.